# How to prove a bound for derivative of Zeta function

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

For some c > 0.

$\xi''(s) = O(\log^3(t))$ for $|t| \geq 2$ and $\sigma > 1 - \frac{c}{\log(|t|)}$.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to learn the subject.  Why don't you take a book like Montgomery and Vaughan, and work through it fully?   Questions like this would be easy for you to sort out then.

Comment: Also, this may be standard notation in the field, but without stating the relationship between $s$, $t$ and $\sigma$, your question is incomprehensible to a non-specialist.

Comment: @JeremyRickard the notation is standard in analytic number theory: $s = \sigma + it$.